# Is there any better way to tune this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have the below query and would like to know if there is any better way to tune it?

```
MERGE INTO target_table TARGET USING
(SELECT DISTINCT g1.column_name
FROM test_gtt1 g1,
test_gtt2 g2
WHERE g1.column_name = g2.column_name
AND g1.diff_id      IS NULL
AND g2.diff_id      IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT g1.column_name
FROM test_gtt1 g1,
test_gtt2 g2
WHERE 
g1.column_name  = g2.column_name
AND g1.diff_id = g2.diff_id
AND g1.diff_id IS NOT NULL
AND g2.diff_id IS NOT NULL
) SOURCE ON ( TARGET.column_name = SOURCE.column_name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TARGET.column_name2 = 123;
```

Comment: Your logic is very confused.  For instance why use `select distinct ... union all ... select distinct ` instead of `select ... union ... select `?  In short, please explain your business rules instead of making us guess then from a shonky piece of code with no context.

Comment: Tuning is all about the details.  Which version of Oracle?  How many rows in all teh tables?  How many rows in the USING result set?  How many rows get updated?  How long does it take?  How quickly do you want it to run?  What's the explain plan?  Which columns are indexed?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the data types, indexes and the generated plan are (it would have been helpful if you'd provided this).

But the union is obviously redundant:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g1.column_name
FROM test_gtt1 g1,
test_gtt2 g2
WHERE g1.column_name = g2.column_name
AND ((g1.diff_id IS NULL
      AND g2.diff_id IS NULL)
     OR (g1.diff_id IS NOT NULL
         AND g2.diff_id IS NOT NULL))
```

**update**

It occured to me (when replying to APC's comment) that it would also be possible to get the same result using....

```
SELECT DISTINCT g1.column_name
FROM test_gtt1 g1,
test_gtt2 g2
WHERE g1.column_name = g2.column_name
AND DECODE(g1.diff_id, NULL, -1, 1)=DECODE(g2.diff_id, NULL, -1, 1);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking that query can produce a different result set from the one posted - it's UNION ALL not UNION - but I think your version is more correct in this particular case.

Comment: No, it won't return a different result set - there is no intersection of the 2 SELECTs in the original statement.

Comment: Only if `column_name` is unique in both tables, which we don't know.  Otherwise it is possible for both sides of the query to return say 42.  So the original query would have two rows for 42 and your will have one.  As I said, in this case one row would be the more correct result.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to test for `diff_id is null` and `diff_id is not null` if you're going to be combining those two sets with UNION:

```
       select * from foo where bar is null
       union all
       select * from foo where bar is not null
```

is the same as

```
       select * from foo
```

Comment: Actually he wants to exclude the rows for which diff_id is null in either of the table, but not both.

Comment: I overlooked `AND g1.diff_id = g2.diff_id`.  What if g1.diff_id is null and g2.diff_id is not null?